# How python sys.path works on IIS SERVER?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iis, sys.path

problem : 1

I was wondering how sys.path works on server when we deploy our codes on server.
I have created a local package called "mypackage" where all my modules are there.
As far as i know python able to fetch modules from the path which are listed in sys.path.
But when we deploy our codes on server, the path which is listed in sys.path isn't available there but 
it is successfully importing my modules on server how?

problem 2:
i have created a two instances on server one is staging and another is testing,
In testing all module picked up from the right place, but in staging environment my modules are picked up
from testing folder why ?

Comment: IIS just provider a handler to proxy to python.exe. So pyhton just handle the sys.path. But it is also executed under application pool identity. So you may need to ensure app pool identity have permission to access the path.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a file, something like this instead of hardcoding in sys.path

```
import sys

def add_path(path):
    if path not in sys.path:
        sys.path.insert(0, path)

dir_path = os.path.abspath(__file__)
add_path(dir_path)
```